# Show div when radio button is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I'm trying to do the same like an [already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173209/jquery-show-div-when-radio-button-selected).
The problem: I have 40 divs that are to be shown and I don't want 10 lines of code for each one...

Has anyone tips to give on this topic? Thx guys. :)

Comment: what you have tried?? show the code

Comment: The answer should work for you as well, except instead of using an id, you can use a class. Or you can put your 40 divs inside a div with an id like in the linked answer.

Comment: @ManojDhiman No code so far because I have no idea how to deal with that case without messy code.

Answer (score 1):

try this . you just need to replace id with class.

After your comment .here are two demo [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/z92rbxdh/) and [demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/z92rbxdh/1/) I think you want something like this . It is showing the next div with selection . if you want to show save div.then change

`var value=$(this).attr('value');` to `var value=$(this).attr('value')-1;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       $('.show-me').hide();
       var value=$(this).attr('value');
       $( ".show-me:eq("+value+")" ).show();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form-id'>
    <input value='1' name='test' type='radio' />radio1
    <input value='2' name='test' type='radio' />radio2
    <input value='3' name='test' type='radio' />radio3
    <input value='4' name='test' type='radio' />radio4
    <input value='5' name='test' type='radio' />radio5<br />
    <input value='6' name='test' type='radio' />radio6
    <input value='7' name='test' type='radio' />radio7
    <input value='8' name='test' type='radio' />radio8
    <input value='9' name='test' type='radio' />radio9
    <input value='10' name='test' type='radio' />radio10
    
</form>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 1</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 2</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 3</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 4</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 5</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 6</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 7</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 8</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 9</div>
    <div class='show-me' style='display:none'>Div 10</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer... this isn't what I'm searching though.

I'm looking for something that shows the next div.
Thus it's not really a duplicate.

Like I click the first, the second shows up. When I click the second the third shows up and so on. Kinda hard to explain.