# Hide different divs with different ratio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, checked

[Got this code in the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173209/show-div-when-radio-button-selected)
Hi!
How can I transform this code to be "universal". For now it will only work for one case. If i have two it will not work.

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'watch-me') {
            $('#show-me').show();           
       }
       else {
            $('#show-me').hide();   
       }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12">
  <label>Are you a member?</label>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div id="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Use classnames instead of Ids

Comment: Universal in the sense?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @DaniP Thank you I will try that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy When I say "universal" is something that work win multiple cases, with different divs. For now this code will only work the the #show-me div

Comment: @demo If I create another ratio to show another div. It will not work. This code is too specific. Am I making me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a common `class` and do dom traversal with respect to the selected radio button.

---

***Things to be noted:***

1. Use change event instead of click event for radio button.
2. Use the value to detect the radio button instead of sniffing its id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
      $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.show-me').toggle(this.value == "yes");           
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12">
  <label>Are you a member?</label>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: @RaRajaprabhu Aravindasamy Amazing, perfect!
Thank you!

Comment: Note: If you use a delegated event handler, attached to `document`, you do not need a DOM ready handler and it is more efficient/faster to connect to lots of elements.

Comment: @GoneCoding Instead of document we have to use the closest static parent to attach the delegated event handler to gain more performance.

Comment: That is a common misunderstanding. The speed difference is negligible. The usual reason to target a static parent is to localise the range of elements that will respond. In any case, your current example is less efficient at event registration time as that search filter is "relatively" slow. Saying that your answer is still better than the others.

Answer (score 3):

> If i have two it will not work.

**Why ?** :: Because if you just copy/paste the same structure twice you will have duplicated ID's and that's invalid, making your JS code useless.

What you need is an structure based on classnames or attr something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('value') == 'yes') {
            $(this).siblings('.show-me').show();           
       }
       else {
            $(this).siblings('.show-me').hide();   
       }
   });
});
```

```css
.show-me {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12">
  <label>Are you a member?</label>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>
    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me2"  value="yes" name="Member2" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me2">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo2" value="no" name="Member2" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo2">No</label>
    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber2">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber2" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying going this way. I should had go with classes and the value attr!. Great

Answer (score 1):

For different values you can do something like this.

```js
function showHide(input){
  var attrVal = $(input).attr('id');
     switch (attrVal) {
         case 'watch-me':
         $('#show-me-2').hide();   
         $('#show-me').show();     
         break;
         case "watch-me-maybe":
         $('#show-me').hide();  
          $('#show-me-2').show();   
          break;
       default :
         $('#show-me-2').hide();  
         $('#show-me').hide();  
          break;
         }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
      showHide(this); 
  });
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
     showHide(this);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12">
  <label>Are you a member?</label>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input" checked="checked">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me-maybe" value="maybe" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberMaybe">Maybe</label>

    <div id="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="show-me-2" class="medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber2">Please enter your Membership number2</label>
        <input id="memberNumber2" name="memberNumber2" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I opted for the RajaprabhuAravindasamy answer due its simplicity. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i tried to make this work without taking in consideration any `class` or `id` , just `html` structure.

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3pkutL2/1/)**

1. **never** use duplicate ID's ! do not put same ID on 2 or more different elements , use classes instead
2. use `attr('value')` to find your elements instead of `attr('id')`

JQ :

```
$("fieldset").each(function(){
 var showme = $(this).children("div"),
     radio = $(this).children('input[type="radio"]')
 $(radio).change(function() {
   if($(this).attr('value') == 'yes') {
        $(showme).show();           
   }
   else {
        $(showme).hide();   
   }
 });
});
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: Dear @MihaiT , Thank you very much but I opted for the RajaprabhuAravindasamy answer due its simplicity. Again, thank you!

Comment: i saw that answer . it's a very good one. in my answer, as you can see, i didn't use any `class` or `id` . tried to make it as 'universal' as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version for you. It uses a delegated event attached to document (which always exists, so a DOM ready handler is not needed). The relatively slow filter expression (`:radio`) is only run at event time (when it does not matter):

```js
$(document).on('change', ':radio', function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.show-me').toggle(this.value == "yes");           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12">
  <label>Are you a member?</label>
</div>
<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="medium-6">
  <fieldset class="form-row" id="Member">
    <input type="radio" id="watch-me"  value="yes" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="watch-me">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="MemberNo" value="no" name="Member" class="tap-input">
    <label for="MemberNo">No</label>

    <div class="show-me" class=" medium-12">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="memberNumber">Please enter your Membership number</label>
        <input id="memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="inputfield" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```