# radio button show hide divs is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done some code for radio button group to show and hide the divs. but this code is not working properly. could you please look into this. Thank you.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div> 
            <h3 class="radio_heading">Radio Button Group</h3>
                <form>                             
                    <label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" checked/>Book</label>
                    <label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Non-Book</label>
                </form>


                <div id="blk-1" class="toHide">     
                    <form action="success1.html">     
                        Name1:<input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">     
                    </form>     
                </div>
                <div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">     
                    <form action="success1.html">     
                        Name2:<input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


 $(function() {
        $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any code to show/hide anything?!

Comment: add a fiddle so we can see more

Comment: added jquery function below.

Comment: Works for me http://www.bootply.com/WRgLrFIsW7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173209/show-div-when-radio-button-selected

Comment: Now you have to define: `this code is not working properly`???

Comment: @j08691:- I am using IE edge . Is this a cause to not working? i ran the same code in IE edge, it is not working.

Comment: Firstly, you should use `change` event, not click BUT i don't see how it would be an issue on Edge. And have you tested j08691's link:  http://www.bootply.com/WRgLrFIsW7  Same issue on your Edge?

Comment: I just tested it on Edge, no issue. So silly question but have you clear browser's cache?!

Comment: @A.Wolff :- Yes, I cleared cache also. The mistake i did here is used jquery 1.2 version instead of 2.1/2.2 versions. May be this cause the issue. After added jquery 2.1 , it is working perfectly.

Comment: @RaviKChowdary That's sillier mistake then... ;) Glad you have fixed it!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code, added the jQuery library, and it appears to work fine.

```js
 $(function() {
        $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div> 
            <h3 class="radio_heading">Radio Button Group</h3>
                <form>                             
                    <label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" checked/>Book</label>
                    <label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Non-Book</label>
                </form>


                <div id="blk-1" class="toHide">     
                    <form action="success1.html">     
                        Name1:<input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">     
                    </form>     
                </div>
                <div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">     
                    <form action="success1.html">     
                        Name2:<input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Problem of code is in using click event `$("[name=toggler]").click()`. At least change it to `$("[name=toggler]").change()`