# How to show container using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to build a smiley survey using only Front-End.

After hitting one of my radio buttons, the content should become visible for comments. My CSS is set up to `display: none`.

I have tried to do it using jQuery but nothing seems to be working.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + id).addClass('face-cc').siblings().removeClass('none');
});
```

```html
<div class="cc-selector row" id="moods">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="radio" type="radio" name="smile" value="angry" />
    <label class="face-cc" for="angry">
       <span class="far fa-angry" aria-hidden="div"></span>
     </label>
    <p>Terrible</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input type="radio" name="smile" value="grin-stars"/>
    <label class="face-cc" for="grin-stars">
      <span class="far fa-grin-stars" aria-hidden="div"></span>
    </label>
    <p>Excellent</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="none" id="text">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="row p-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group shadow-textarea">
            <label for="feedback">If you have any additional feedback, 
               please let us know below...
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control p-2" id="comment" rows="7" 
              cols="20" placeholder="Comment here...">
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Comment: First of you have a problem here `$('text' + id)` you seem to be missing a . or #

Comment: also I guess you need to remove NONE from current element and remove it from siblings, don't you?

Comment: Your title contains "does not work" and it is useless, at least try to describe any errors / warnings you have. Regarding your question, `$('radio')` is wrong because `radio` it is not a valid HTML tag, you should write `$("input[type='radio']")`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, thats my first question here, so obviously I am making the dumb mistakes . Next time will be more specific!

Comment: I have changed everything what you suggested guys it still doesn't work

Comment: `$('radio')` is like saying: *"Hey jQuery! Go find my `<radio></radio>` element, willya"*

Comment: You have an out-of-nowhere `</a>` wandering around your site. please Find a better code editor that can automatically point you out markup issues!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks so much for your suggestions! What code editor do you recommend?

Comment: @Andrew so I`ve changed to $("input[type='radio']") and it still doesn't catch that. Thanks for your suggestions so far. :)

Comment: $("input[type='radio']").change(function(event) {
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 $('text' + id).addClass('text').siblings().removeClass('none');
  });

Comment: Check your code, there are two `</div>` without the corresponding opening tag; there also are `id` attributes with the same value, which is forbidden. Please check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d86bzwrk/

Comment: @Patrycja for a code editor you want to use anything that has linter rules and coloring for you. Try VS code or Sublime and add the extensions for JS/CSS/HTML accordingly (a quick google search will help you more in detail)

Comment: Thanks @AGE I am installing VsCode extensions now! :)

Comment: @Patrycja if you need a quick editor for working on the browser I personally like jsFiddle, there are many out there but this one is very simple to use to get started (and it is almost the same one used on this website to write code Q/A)

Comment: Thanks so much for all comments problem solved, app works! Win! And thanks for the warm welcome. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things incorrect with your approach. First is your use of the radio buttons in the HTML. For you to easily grab their individual click events and inspect their value, you want to add `id` attributes to them. I added some id's myself based on the radio button's `name` attribute that you already added.

Second, the jQuery which you used I changed completely to match thew use of the `id` attribute which I just added. This will look to see which radio button we just clicked on and if it matches the id of the radio button which will show the element, then we show the element accordingly.

You can also accomplish show/hide via CSS. **I removed your CSS class** of `display: none;` for the above to work, but you can keep it and use jQuery's [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) or `addClass` and `removeClass` using the above logic.

A few other comments. I simplified the logic by adding a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which you can read more on if you have not seen this syntax.

Last but **not least** is a quick search on StackOverflow can help, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173209/show-div-when-radio-button-selected) which is the exact fix which you needed in your code from a jQuery perspective. I took the time to explain my approach here because you also needed HTML and CSS fixes to your approach.

If you think this answer helped, then feel free to 'accept' or 'mark up' the answer and welcome to Stack Overflow.

```js
var text = $('#text');
var showId = 'grin-stars';

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('id') === showId ? text.show() : text.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cc-selector row" id="moods">
  <div class="col">
    <input id="angry" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="angry" />
    <label class="face-cc" for="angry">
       <span class="far fa-angry" aria-hidden="div"></span>
     </label>
    <p>Terrible</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input id="grin-stars" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="grin-stars"/>
    <label class="face-cc" for="grin-stars">
      <span class="far fa-grin-stars" aria-hidden="div"></span>
    </label>
    <p>Excellent</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="text">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="row p-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group shadow-textarea">
            <label for="feedback">
               If you have any additional feedback, please let us know below...
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control p-2" id="comment" rows="7" 
              cols="20" placeholder="Comment here...">
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and explanation. Thanks so much, still needs to learn a lot! :)

Comment: no worries, if this answer is correct please accept it and let me know if you have questions

Comment: tried yesterday several times but this still doesn't trigger the action after hitting any radio button. My Comment section is hidden all the time I just need to show this section when user will choose if he is happy or not about given service. Obviously there is more faces than just terrible and excellent but it doesn't do anything at all after checking radio.

Comment: Hey, checked today morning still doesn't work. Action does not trigger the comment section. :(

Comment: is the HTML/Javascript in your project exactly the same as the one in my example? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I`ve done that. I followed your logic and I figured out. Thank you so so much for your help:)!